# how play video on listview where on is focuses

Tags: android, xml, listview, video, adapter

I write application for android but have some problems

```
package com.example.test5.timeline;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import com.example.test5.R;
import com.example.test5.testmsgActivity;

public class TimelineAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private VideoView vv;
    private TextView comment;
    private LinearLayout video_layout, user_field, video_name_field,
            users_info_field;
    private int screen_w = 0, screen_h = 0;
    private ImageView user_profile_image, google_plus;

    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;
    ArrayList<SimplePost> posts;

    TimelineAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SimplePost> post) {
        ctx = context;
        posts = post;
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    // кол-во элементов
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return posts.size();
    }

    // элемент по позиции
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return posts.get(position);
    }

    // id по позиции
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    // пункт списка
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // используем созданные, но не используемые view
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.simple_post_layout, parent, false);
        }

        SimplePost p = getProduct(position);

        screen_w = 1080;
        screen_h = 1920;

        comment = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.video_coment_count);

        vv = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_video);
        vv.setVideoPath("http://server_ip/uploads/CAM00262.mp4");
        vv.getLayoutParams().height = screen_w;
        vv.getLayoutParams().width = screen_w;

        video_layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.video_layout);
        video_layout.getLayoutParams().height = screen_w;
        video_layout.getLayoutParams().width = screen_w;

        user_field = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.user_field);

        video_name_field = (LinearLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.video_name_field);

        users_info_field = (LinearLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.users_info_field);

        google_plus = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.video_plus_share);

        user_profile_image = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.user_profile_image);

        video_layout.getLayoutParams().height = vv.getLayoutParams().height;
        video_layout.getLayoutParams().width = vv.getLayoutParams().height;

        comment.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {
                        vv.start();
                    }
                }
            );
        return view;
    }

    public DisplayMetrics getScreenSize() {
        testmsgActivity ttt = new testmsgActivity();
        return ttt.getScreenSize();
    }

    SimplePost getProduct(int position) {
        return ((SimplePost) getItem(position));
    }

}
```

user_timeline_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/TimelinelistView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >
                    </ListView>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

simple_post.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/user_field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50px"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/user_profile_image"
                android:layout_width="50px"
                android:layout_height="50px"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2px"
                android:background="@drawable/photo" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_profile_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Vahagn Vardanyan" >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/video_name_field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60px"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/video_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="my first text video  #first" >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/video_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <VideoView
                android:id="@+id/user_video"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="150px"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/users_info_field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/video_view_count"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center" 
                android:text="view" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/video_like_count"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="like" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/video_coment_count"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="play_video"
                android:text="comment" >
            </TextView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/video_plus_share"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30px"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/plus" />
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

where I insert post array on VistView (user_timeline_layout.xml) after press comment textview for play video, in this moment played all video . please help, how I can play video in x position or where in is focuses.